# How to check if a phone is obstructed by something?

Tags: java, javascript, android, api, cordova

Is there an API that would let me know if my phone is behind a wall, or something solid?

I am interested to do this in javascript or java for an Android phone.

Or, how would one figure out if the phone is obstructed by something, by using the hardware available in the phone..?

Any ideas?

Comment: you could probably use signal strength as an indicator

Comment: ...more like use signal strength sudden variation.

Comment: Echolocation or signal strength would be my first thoughts.

Comment: signal strength might not do it, the distance might be an issue

Comment: What is your operational definition of "obstructed"? Obstructed from what?

Comment: @apsillers, good question. If i get the location of a phone on a google map, and the phone is an a coffee shop, then the phone is obstructed by a few walls in all directions

Comment: So you basically want to detect solid objects around the phone? I'm judging from this comment and the one about detecting a statue or a fence in an open area.
It would help if you gave us an example of the intended app use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmmm u could use the GPS, when GPS is into a home, the lattitude and longitude are 0 cause can't attach to the GPS satellite, u can use this 0 as a flag, to do what u like to do

Comment: not sure.... what if i am just behind a open wall, or statue, etc

Comment: i think this is the best i can get. :)